# Gallery Image Transition

Tags: php, html, css, fancybox

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using Aurigma Image Uploader and FancyBox to produce [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/test.php) gallery page. The problem I'm having is that the images are positioned to go vertically down the page, whereas I would prefer them to go horizontally across the page, creating separate rows of images, one underneath the other.

I appreciate that some may not know anything about the Aurigma package, but I think I'm right in saying that 'Fancybox' is a little more widely used.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps provide somne guidance please on the settings I would need to change within the Fancybox script so that the images are positioned horizontally rather than vertically.

Many thanks

**.ccs file extract**

```
.gallery-image-list { padding: 0; list-style-type: none; }
.gallery-image-list .item { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin: 5px; padding: 15px; white-space: nowrap; width: 150px; float:left; }
.gallery-image-list .wide-item { width: 250px; }
.gallery-image-list .item .preview { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
.gallery-image-list .item .data { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; font-size: 95%; }
.gallery-image-list .item .data li { margin-bottom: 5px; }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to display them the way you want with html? I don't see what fancybox has to do with displaying images on the page.

Comment: What does FancyBox have to do with anything?  It's just for displaying the modal popup containing the image.

Comment: This a css issue, not a fancybox issue.

Comment: Sincere apologies. A beginners mistake. You are quite right, this is not Fancybox, but a .css file issue. Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is to add `float:left;` to your item class in css.

Comment: Many thanks for this, you're spot on. Apologies if this should be a new question, but I can't seem to position the images so they are the same width apart, and they don't appear on more than one row. They just end up as 'jumbled mess'. I've located the .css file and added it to my original post. I just wondered whether you could pehrpas take a look at this and show me what I need to look at to get the spacing right. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM give your item class defined width and height. Also, please accept the answer. Thanks.